# Strange behavior of ZIO's map method or yield in for comprehension

Tags: scala, for-comprehension, zio

I faced that `ZIO.map` invokes private `ZIO.succeedNow` which seems will fail running fiber without any chance of handle error
Here is an example:

```
  private val program: ZIO[Any, Throwable, Int] = for {
    _ <- ZIO.succeed(println("Start"))
  } yield 1 / 0

  override def run: ZIO[Any, Any, Unit] = program
    .catchAll(e => ZIO.succeed(println(e.getMessage))) *>
    ZIO.succeed(println("DONE"))
```

The output will never print "DONE" in console
The same behavior observed when I'll change the `val program` to:

```
  private val program: ZIO[Any, Throwable, Int] = for {
    _ <- ZIO.succeed(println("Start"))
    r <- ZIO.succeed(1 / 0)
  } yield r
```

But when I'm excluding invocation of `succeed()` everything works fine and I'm getting "DONE" in console
This snippet bellow works as expected

```
  private val program: ZIO[Any, Throwable, Int] = for {
    _ <- ZIO.succeed(println("Start"))
    r <- ZIO.from(1 / 0)
  } yield r
```

And finally `catchAll` is invoked
The question is why `ZIO.map` suppose that passed function should not be failed, and why if it fails I have no chance to handle this error?

Answer (score 3):

In your first example, as you said, you're using `ZIO#map()` which semantic/contract is to be used with a function that do not raise exceptions.

If you break this intended usage, you get a **defect** ([read more about it](https://zio.dev/reference/error-management/types/)) which as you noticed is not caught by `catchAll` but would be using `catchAllDefect` ([read more about it](https://zio.dev/reference/error-management/recovering/catching)).

In your second example, the result is the same because this time you break the intended usage of `ZIO.succeed()` by giving it a non successful value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  
Seems my confusing grows from that fact that I used to understand ```map``` as some computation inside container, and if it fails it will not let exception to run outside, like as ```Try[A]```. Will take a closer look to defects, thank you

Comment: There's no single semantic for `map` regarding this. With `Option[A]`, the exception would "escape". With `ZIO` it goes to the defect channel. With `Try` it goes to the `Failure` channel.

Comment: The why is actually easy to understand. The error channel from ZIO is typed. And not bound to `Throwable` like `Try`. If `map` or `ZIO.succeed` would lift the error to the error channel, you would mess with custom error types. After `map` it would always be `Any`. In addition, the error channel represents expected failure. Therefore you have to let zio know, that you expect an error. Therefore `effect.flatMap(_ => ZIO.attempt(<code that might throw>))`

Comment: Thank you, it was really mistake from my side to consider ```ZIO#map``` semantic to be the same as ```Try.map```